# Unreadable Notebook: C:\file path UnicodeDecodeError('utf-8) for Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to open a notebook file that I was working on 3 days ago, however, I get the following error Unreadable Notebook: C:\file path UnicodeDecodeError('utf-8) for Jupyter Notebook. How can I get this file to work again.
I've reinstalled Anaconda and tried opening the file on different computers but it still doesn't work

Comment: What did you use the last time to edit the notebook? Open it in Notepad++ and see the encoding, it's probably corrupted. Set the encoding to utf-8 and save it.

Comment: The last time I editted the file was using Jupyterlab. I've changed the encoding from ANSI to utf-8 and saved the file. However, i get this error when I try to open the file  ->       
  Unreadable Notebook: C:file path NotJSONError("Notebook does not appear to be JSON:

Comment: I can't reproduce this error from the little info you provide.

Comment: Your notebook appears to be broken sadly

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem and this is what worked for me.

Open the problem notebook in a text editor and copy all the text. Open a new file in your text editor and paste in the text, then save the file. In my case the text editor did not have the option to save as a Jupyter Notebook, so I saved as .txt.

Move the file into your Jupyter area. Rename it so the ending is .ipynb and not .txt. Then open the file as a notebook.

As I read through the now-working notebook I saw some comments had what looked like Chinese characters in them. I don't know exactly what happened there to make those appear but if you used Ctrl+/ to comment like I do then it's possible that is where the issue is in your notebook. So if my janky method of converting file types does not work for you and you still really want to save your notebook enough to manually dig through all the markup and text then you can try checking your comments in the file to see if there are odd characters in there.